# Hash String does not equal to Copied Hash String from console C#

Tags: c#, encryption, hash, cryptography

I created hash. Than I printed it in console. Copied hash value and put it to code for comparsion. But it yield that they are not same.

```
        String input = "Hello";
        String key = "Key";
        Byte[] hashKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(hashKey);
        Byte[] computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        String computedHashString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(computedHash);
        Console.WriteLine("Hash value of your input: .{0}.", computedHashString);

        if ("↨:?☼??W?u$YLR;?←?T?j" == computedHashString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("They are same!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("They are NOT same!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: console]

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of a hash isn't UTF-8-encoded text, and shouldn't be treated that way. Convert it to hex or base64. For example:

```
string computedHashString = Convert.ToBase64String(computedHash);
```

Fundamentally, you need to treat data carefully. Converting the result of a hash to text is like trying to load an mp3 file into a picture viewer, or trying to unzip the result of applying a compression algorithm.